# Couchbase Server, Detect Document Changes

Tags: node.js, couchbase

A little of background, I have a Couchbase to store endpoints that other developers souldn't know, on the app init I load the endpoints in a var. Sometimes we change the endpoints but when we do we need to restart node.

So I want to detect document changes in Couchbase Server, to make another call to the bucket and update the documents.

I read about Sync-Gateway but I think is only valid for Couchbase Mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can interface with the [REST API](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.5/references/sync-gateway/index.html) provided by Sync Gateway to detect [document changes](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.5/references/sync-gateway/rest-api/index.html?v=1.4#/database/get__db___changes) . You will have to [configure](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.5/guides/sync-gateway/config-properties/index.html#1.5/databases-foo_db-import_docs) your Sync Gateway so it imports the documents from the Couchbase server and adds relevant "sync" metadata to the documents.

Which version of the server are you using - depending on your response, what you would have to do will vary.